# error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2. [ng]

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

ERROR in src/app/pages/main/main.page.ts(61,27): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
[ng] 
When i run the below code.I followed this tutorial for ionic 4 https://www.techiediaries.com/inappbrowser-ionic-v3/
The line 61 is InAppBrowser(........)

```
openUrl() {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            let browser = new InAppBrowser("https://www.techiediaries.com","_system");

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the tutorial you linked, InAppBrowser has a `create` function which you can use to do this;

```
let browser = this.InAppBrowser.create("https://www.techiediaries.com","_system);
```

The error you received is due to you using the constructor for InAppBrowser, which does not take any arguments itself.

The [Ionic Framework documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/in-app-browser/) for InAppBrowser has some sample usage too which you may find helpful.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/pages/main/main.page.ts(59,32): error TS2339: Property 'InAppBrowser' does not exist on type 'MainPage'.

Comment: @sobha can you include a larger snippet of your code so we can see where the problem is coming from

Comment: Thanks for you kindness.I solved it  with the reference you gave me